# Android auto - Code to push unreadConversation not working

Tags: android, android-auto

I am using a desktop head unit and i have the following code to push the conversation to the unit, keep in mind i set null on the pending intents because i dont need any hooks/callbacks. I only want send a notification when android auto is active. Here is the code not working:

```
private void pushAndroidAutoUnreadConversation(String msg) {
// Build a RemoteInput for receiving voice input in a Car Notification
RemoteInput remoteInput = new RemoteInput.Builder(MY_VOICE_REPLY_KEY)
.setLabel(msg)
.build();

// Create an unread conversation object to organize a group of messages
// from a particular sender.
UnreadConversation.Builder unreadConvBuilder =
new UnreadConversation.Builder("my apps conversation")
  .setReadPendingIntent(null)
  .setReplyAction(null, remoteInput);

unreadConvBuilder.addMessage(msg)
.setLatestTimestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());


Bitmap largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
R.drawable.icon);


NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
  .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
  .setLargeIcon(largeIcon).setContentTitle(msg);

notificationBuilder.extend(new NotificationCompat.CarExtender()
.setUnreadConversation(unreadConvBuilder.build()));

NotificationManagerCompat msgNotificationManager =
NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
msgNotificationManager.notify("my_apps_tag",
Integer.parseInt(MY_VOICE_REPLY_KEY), notificationBuilder.build());

}
```

MY_VOICE_REPLY_KEY is just a number, its 9675

and here is my build.gradle file:

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.myapp.easy"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 21
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('old_proguard-android.txt')
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-4.1.1.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.2'
}
```

here is a section of the manifest:

```
   <application
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.car.application"
            android:resource="@xml/automotive_app_desc" />
```

and here is automotive_app_desc.xml which i put in the xml folder:

```
 <automotiveApp>
    <uses name="notification"/>
</automotiveApp>
```

i am following the official tutorial [here](http://developer.android.com/training/auto/messaging/index.html)

I am assuming when i create the notification a physical notification is suppose to appear on in android auto dashboard, i see nothing. But on the mobile device i see my notification.  Let me explain whats happening.  I am creating a message way before i plug into the car.  So this method gets run when user is disconnected from the car. When the user connects to the android auto im expecting that this notification should show on the dashboard, but its not but yet i see it on the mobile devices notification tray.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found the issue. I was passing null for pending intents.  It does not want that.  I had to make pending intents for message heard and message reply and actually set them in the UnreadConversation.Builder  like this:

```
UnreadConversation.Builder unreadConvBuilder =
            new UnreadConversation.Builder("reminder note")
                    .setReadPendingIntent(msgHeardPendingIntent)
                    .setReplyAction(msgHeardPendingIntent, remoteInput);
```

so it does not like null for setReadPendingIntent & setReplyAction it seems.